# Preload data from database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do something like this to preload all data, so I don't have to a database call every time the loop runs.

```
# Get all data and do some eager loading
bets = Bet.find(:all, :include => :team_id)

games = Game.find(:all)

games.each do |game|
  bets.find_all_by_user_id(user.id) # Now I want to get the specific bets, but I can't do  find() on the returned array
end
```

and the other way I've tried

```
bets = Bet.where(:user_id => users) # users are an array of ID's

games = Game.find(:all)

games.each do |game|
  bets.find_all_by_user_id(user.id) # This works, but it makes a db call every time, which makes the site really slow.
end
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is to load all data, and then use it in the loop without having to contact the database. What is the best approach to this?

Comment: You really have to provide more info on architectural structure of your application before any suggestion can be given. Is it web? mobile? windows forms? Hows DAL designed -through web services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to make the call at some previous point, save the data in a variable, and then access that variable in the loop. Something like this:

```
games = Game.all

bets = Bet.all

games.each do |game|
    bets.select {|b| b.user_id == user.id}
end
```

Don't use finder methods inside the array: if you do, you'll query the database again. Stick with the [Ruby enumerable methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) to act on the data you already have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do... Where did you get *user* variable. Why did you need to show **all** bets in each game? So, I'm hoping that your Bet belongs to User and posted to some Game. And you need to list all Bets for each Game that User had participated at? So, in user should be:

```
has_many :bets    
has_many :games, :through => :bets
```

And now:

```
user.games.all( :include => :bets ).each do |game|
  game.bets # will be already loaded
end
```

Here:
*:include - Names associations that should be loaded alongside. The symbols named refer to already defined associations.* - quote from [Rails API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class).